# Why is import-module or dot sourcing a file not working in powershell scripts?

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code

I am developing and running PS scripts in VS Code using the PowerShell Extension. I have defined a number of functions in a separate PS module file, which I have saved here:

`C:\Users\MyName\Documents\PowerShell\Modules\PowerBiFunctions\PowerBiFunctions.psm1`

But when attempting to import the module with

`Import-Module PowerBiFunctions`

or a copy placed in the same directory as the script

`Import-Module $PSScriptRoot\PowerBiFunctions.psm1`

I get the following error:

`Import-Module : The specified module 'PowerBiFunctions' was not loaded because no valid module file was found in any module directory.`

In addition, I have made a copy of the file with the .ps1 extension and placed in the same directory. However, I can't seem to include it with simple dot sourcing:

`.\PowerBiFunctions.ps1`

or

`. .\PowerBiFunctions.ps1`

What seems to be the problem?

Answer (score 4):

Create a [**module manifest**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/module/how-to-write-a-powershell-module-manifest?view=powershell-7.1):

```
# cd to module folder
Set-Location C:\Users\MyName\Documents\PowerShell\Modules\PowerBiFunctions\

# create new manifest file
New-ModuleManifest .\PowerBiFunctions.psd1 -RootModule .\PowerBiFunctions.psm1 -FunctionsToExport list,of,exported,function,names
```

Now you can import it by name:

```
Import-Module PowerBiFunctions
```